# Code Hinting: How to view classes like dreamweaver in Brackets?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver, frontend, adobe-brackets

I've been using Brackets for a while, I'm in love with it but what I really hate is typing classes on my own, I can't remember all the classes of Bootstrap, What I really miss is the **drop-down view** like that in Dreamweaver where we can see the list of all those classes while writing html, **is it possible to do so in Brackets**? If so then how?

Comment: Why'd you mark negative I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Install 'Brackets CSS Class Code hint' extension. Place the bootstrap.css in the root folder of your web-project. The relevant classes will then appear as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Install this Extension

Extension Manager

```
Under main menu select File > Extension Manager...
Search for "ACB Bootstrap snippets"
Click "Install"
```

https://github.com/acbarbosa1964/acb-bootstrap-snippets

Comment: Good for Bootstrap v3 only.

Answer (score -2):

Go to **File**, open **Extension Manager**, click **Available** and then use the search input to find Extensions for hinting to add to Brackets.

[image].